# if json data success = true only i want to move to next controller

Tags: json, swift

Depending on the Json data, if `json data (success = true)`, then only I want to move the user to next View Controller.

```
{
 "success": true,
    "message": "Loged In",
    "User_details": {
        "user_id": "208",
        "user_name": "Samad",
        "phone": "9705994458",
        "email": "laddafsamad.12@gmail.com",
        "image": "https://laex.in/testprep/Dashboard/uploads/user/1499063695.jpg"
    }
}
```

Comment: What you have tried so far ?

Comment: Post your code so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
if let responce = yourJson as? [String: Any],
   let isSuccess = responce["success"] as? Bool,
   isSuccess {
     // Send user to next viewcontroller
}
```

Try this code :)

Comment: If you share the code which you have tried till now, then it will be much easier to solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
let result : NSDictionary! = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as! NSDictionary

if let success = result.value(forKey: "success") as? Bool {

  if success {
    // navigate to next viewcontroller
  }

}
```